# Why is "[[ 10 < 2 ]]" true when comparing numbers in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

When I run

```
if [[ 10 < 2 ]]; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

in shell, it returns `yes`. Why? should it be `no`?
And When I run

```
if [[ 20 < 2 ]]; then
  echo "yes"
else
  echo "no"
fi
```

it returns `no`.

Comment: When you were asking the question, the interface should have showed a series of search results for similar questions. Were none of those flagged in the header shown there?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Because you compare strings according to [Lexicographical order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) and not numbers

You may use `[[ 10 -lt 2 ]]` and `[[ 20 -lt 2 ]]`. `-lt` stands for **Less than** (`<`). For **Greater than** (`>`) `-gt` notation can be used instead.

In bash double parenthesis can be used as well for performing numeric comparison:

```
if ((10 < 2)); then echo "yes"; else echo "no"; fi
```

The above example will echo `no`

Comment: I use bash shell

Comment: Sometimes I feel that JavaScript should not be the scapegoat of programming notwithstanding its obfuscated syntax and drunk typecasting wizardry because this ‘feature’ of Bash feels like outright treachery that deserves punishment in the ninth circle of hell. (I was owned by bash string comparison today...)

Comment: @AndreïV.Kostyrka, it should be unsurprising for a language where the [specification says everything is a string](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) to treat everything as strings unless declared otherwise. Not that POSIX sh is a _good_ spec -- it has decades of backwards compatibility constraints obliging it to be a bad one -- but people who try to write shell scripts with no effort to actually learn the language they're writing code in deserve what they get.