# double square brackets always returns True

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

I am learning bash scripting and faced an issue using double square brackets for conditionals.
when I want to *check the command line argument*, the following works:

```
if (($1 > number))
then
    command
```

however, if I use double square brackets, **if condition will always return True**.

```
if [[ $1 > number ]]
then
    command
```

but the mentioned issue, only happens if the passed argument is a *number*!!!!
when I use the same pattern for file checking, the if condition behaves as it should.

```
if [[ -f $1 ]]
then
    command
```

can someone kindly explain to me what am I doing wrong. I just don't get it.
Ubuntu 23.04, bash 5.2.15

Comment: `>` is for string comparisons; for numeric (integer) comparisons you want to use `-gt`

Comment: I would avoid using `[[ ... ]]` for arithmetic altogether. Either use `(( $1 > number ))`  (recommended for `bash`) or `[ "$1" -gt "$number" ]` (recommended for POSIX compatibility).

Comment: See ["Why is `[[ 10 < 2 ]]` true when comparing numbers in bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42745497/why-is-10-2-true-when-comparing-numbers-in-bash) and ["How can I compare numbers in Bash?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668556/how-can-i-compare-numbers-in-bash)

Comment: Whether the characters `0` through `9` sort before or after the character `n` (as the first character in the string `number`) is dependent on your currently configured locale. Thus, the outcome of this comparison is going to differ on what part of the world you run it in (or at least, which part of the world `LC_COLLATE` is configured for).